# Can I prevent Ubuntu One sync files over 100 mb for example?

Tags: files, ubuntu-one

There are some pdf books over 600 mb, and I'm not interesting sync that books. Can I "tells" Ubuntu One that don't sync files over 100 mb without have to move the books of the folders?

ubuntu 10.10

Comment: the service is obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One will normally sync all the files in and directories designated for synchronization so there's no way to do this.